# textarea line break with GD library

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem displying text from textarea with line breaks working with GD `imagecopyresized();` function.

```
<form action="" method="post"> <!--Form Start-->
<textarea name="description">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
                                 <!--php Start-->
<?php 
$image = imagecreatefrompng('bg.png'); //Open background png image

//Setting "text" from textarea,"font" from ttf file,"font size" with int
$text = $_POST['description']; 
$font = 'font.ttf';
$size = 10;

// Create textbox and coordinates
$bbox = imageftbbox($size,0,$font,$text);

$w = $bbox[2]+1 -$bbox[6]+2;
$h = $bbox[3]+1 -$bbox[7]+2;

//Creating new blank image sized by the textbox
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);

//Adding transparent background color for the new image
$black = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
$bg = imagecolortransparent($im,$black);

//Creating new image using also the transparent color for the text
//The resault is a transparent image 
imagefttext($im,$size,0,-$bbox[6]+1,-$bbox[7]+1,$bg,$font,$text]);

//Outputing the image as a png file
imagepng($im,'text_size_image.png',9);

//Open the new file... Again!!
$im2 = imagecreatefrompng('text_size_image.png');

//Setting the alpha settings
imagealphablending($im2,false);
imagesavealpha($im2,true);

//Settin colors for the saved-open image with transparent background
$black2 = imagecolorallocate($im2,0,0,0);
imagecolortransparent($im2,$black2);
$almost_black = imagecolorallocate($im2,43,43,43);

//Creating the text again with visuable color $almost_black
imagefttext($im2,$size,0,-$bbox[6]+1,-$bbox[7]+1,$almost_black,$font,$text);

//Setting a resizer code
if ($w > 272 || $h > 53) {
$new_width = $w -272;
$final_width = 272 + $new_width;

$new_height = $h - 53;
$final_height = $h - $new_height;
}else {
$new_width = 272 - $w;
$final_width = $new_width + $w;

$new_height = 53 - $h;
$final_height = $new_height + $h;
}

//Merging the two images by resizing the image with the text
imagecopyresized($image,$im2,30,384,1,20,$new_width,$new_height,272,53);

//Outputing the final resault
imagepng($image,'final.png',9);

//Free ram memory
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($im2);
?>
</form> <!--The end of the form-->

<img src="final.png"> <!--outputing the image on the browser-->
```

The code works and the transparent text is flawless. But no matter how long I type on the textarea, the text printing on the final image on one line! The only way to get a line break is by typing "enter". How can I solve that?

For instance, take a look here: http://yugiohcardmaker.net At the textarea here you type in and the text sets perfect on the image!

Anyone with any ideas about it?

EDIT:

need help for this cause I get confused. I found this:

```
<?php
function wrap($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $string, $width){

    $ret = "";

    $arr = explode(' ', $string);

foreach ( $arr as $word ){

    $teststring = $ret.' '.$word;
    $testbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $teststring);
    if ( $testbox[2] > $width ){
        $ret.=($ret==""?"":"\n").$word;
    } else {
        $ret.=($ret==""?"":' ').$word;
    }
}

return $ret;
}
?>
```

How can I use it to work with my code now? Thank you

Comment: Usually text entered into an HTML textarea is only broken while displaying the text, but no actual line break is inserted in the value unless the user manually enters it. Although [HTML5 has finally specified the `wrap` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-textarea-wrap), I wouldn’t rely on all browsers supporting it as expected. So that leaves you with breaking the text into separate lines server-side. PHP offers a lot of string functions, so have a look at those and see which one might be applicable here.

Comment: Thank you CBroe, but can you tate a look on the above link I posted? You will se whay I'm looking for. Thanks for you comment and I'll make my research

Comment: @Prime You can look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870384/1415724 After Googling "gd image text wrap php" - the list goes on.